# Sequelize Typescript on delete cascade throwing errors

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I've got a very straightforward FK relationship between Group and GroupAttendee. Whenever I call `Group.destroy()` I'm greeted with a foreign key constraint failure exception on the GroupAttendee entries. I understand how those constraints are supposed to work at the database level but I can't seem to get sequelize-typescript to create?/enforce? them.

I'm including a simplified version of my models to demonstrate my setup:

```
import { Model, Column, AllowNull, HasMany, ForeignKey, DataType, BelongsTo } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { User } from "./User";

class Group extends Model<Group> {

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  title: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  startDate: Date;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  endDate: Date;

  @HasMany(() => GroupAttendee)
  attendees: GroupAttendee[];
}

class GroupAttendee extends Model<GroupAttendee> {

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  userId: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Group)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  groupId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Group, {
    onUpdate: "CASCADE",
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
    hooks: true
  })
  group: Group;
}
```

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should put cascade on `Group` Model , instead of `GroupAttendee` , like this :

```
@HasMany(() => GroupAttendee , {
    onUpdate: "CASCADE",
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
    hooks: true
})
attendees: GroupAttendee[];
```